# Ruby-on-Rails: How do I change default rendering option :layout to 'false'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, layout, configuration, ruby-on-rails-3.1

That's basically it. I want most of the views in my Ruby on Rails 3.1 app to be rendered without layout, as they will be assigned to divs by jQuery, but I don't want to go to every controller action and set `render :layout => false` in the respond_to block.

Is it possible to change the default rendering of views to `:layout => false`? How would I go about configuring that?

Thank you for your help

**EDIT**

I could also solve it with a way to have something along the lines of:

```
if request.xhr?
    format.html { render :layout => false }
end
```

be executed on every respond_to block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
   layout nil # this sets default layout for all actions in this controller
end
```

If you want some more advanced behavior (such as determine de layaout in execution time) you also can pass a block that returns nil or a valid layout name:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
   layout lambda{ ...your stuff... }
end
```

Comment: But the first option seems to leave the page as plain text. I just wanted to omit the layouts/application.html.erb. Can you use the lambda to do that?

Comment: That is because you have your stylesheet_link_tag in your layout. Since you dont include the layout, you dont include the CSS. Instead of this, I would create a simplest_layout.html.erb, with only a head(with css and JS included) and a body tags, an then use
`class UserController < ApplicationController
           layout :simplest_layout        
end`

Comment: Ahhh, of course! Thank you. That seems to be the best solution. So what exactly does the `:layout => false` command do? Does it just keep the head and body of the applicaction.html.erb?
Anyway, I'll implement it with your suggestion!